# div is margin everything else

Tags: html, css, css-float

When I try to position #slider, the navigation and everything above it also positions. Like if they was wrapped in #slider, but they are not

HTML:

```
<div id="slider" class="clearfix">
        <div class="content">
            <h2> This is a header </h2>
            <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim                 veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in                          voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia                        deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
            </p>
        </div><!-- .content -->
        <div class="images">
            <img src="images/slider-twitter.png" alt="">
        </div><!-- .images -->


    </div><!-- #slider -->
```

CSS:

```
#slider {
    margin: 2px auto;
    width: 821px;
}

#slider .images { float: left; }
#slider .content { float: right; width: 365px;  }
```

Working Problem:
http://jsbin.com/oriwe3

Comment: I don't understand what the problem is.

Comment: I don't either - maybe reword what is supposed to be happening.

Comment: Sorry for not describing the problem. When I try to position #slider, the navigation and everything above it also positions. Like if they was wrapped in #slider, but they are not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a clearfix class but you don't define it. I'd recommend giving `.images` a width, too.

An alternative to clearfix is `overflow:hidden;` on `#slider`.

Let me know if that isn't what you need.

Comment: margin: 0 auto; still brings everything down if I tried move #slider http://www.pastie.org/2058133

Comment: It would help knowing how it should look like.